# mixing types java polymorphism. output is not expected

Tags: java

in the following code:

```
class Payment {   }
class CashPayment extends Payment{   }

class Store{    
    public void acceptPayment (Payment p)
    {System.out.println ("Store::Payment");}

}
class FastFoodStore extends Store {
    public void acceptPayment (CashPayment c)
    {System.out.println ("FastFoodStore::CashPayment");}

    public void acceptPayment (Payment p)
    {System.out.println ("FastFoodStore::Payment");}

}

//
public class Example {  

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Store store1 = new Store();
        FastFoodStore sandwitchPlace = new FastFoodStore ();
        Store store2 = new FastFoodStore();


        Payment p1 = new Payment();
        CashPayment cp = new CashPayment();
        Payment p2 = new CashPayment();


        store1.acceptPayment (p1);
        store1.acceptPayment (cp);
        store1.acceptPayment (p2); 

        sandwitchPlace.acceptPayment (p1);
        sandwitchPlace.acceptPayment (cp);
        sandwitchPlace.acceptPayment (p2);

        store2.acceptPayment (p1);
        store2.acceptPayment (cp);
        store2.acceptPayment (p2);



    }   
}
```

what I really don't understand is why

```
store2.acceptPayment (cp);
```

will display FastFoodStore::Payment but not FastFoodStore::CashPayment?
store2 will basically call the methods in FastFoodStore at runtime and pass a CashPayment type parameter. In that case, FastFoodStore::CashPayment is displayed.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a complicated division of effort between compile time and run time in deciding which method to call. See [Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12) for the full story on this.

In your example, when the target expression is of type Store, the compiler will see only the Store acceptPayment method, which expects a Payment argument. That commits to calling a method that takes a Payment argument.

At run time, only the `public void acceptPayment (Payment p)` method in FastFoodStore, the class of the target object, is considered.

Comment: does that mean if I add another method like    public void acceptPayment (CashPayment c)
in the class Store, the output of store2.acceptPayment (cp); will be FastFoodStore::CashPayment?

Comment: oh yea....just tested it on eclipse. i finally understand now. you are awesome!!! thank you so much